# Set the value of multiple cells based on a the number of days in a month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I figured out `=day(eomonth(now(),0))` returns the number of days in a month. How would I set the value of A2 and the number of days down to be each number? Meaning, if there were thirty days in the month, from A2 to A32, it would count up for each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&EOMONTH(TODAY(); -1)+1):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(TODAY(); 0)))))
```

[image: 0]